# createMediaElementSource not playing audio even after connecting source to the destination

Tags: javascript, html

As mentioned in the title, after using `createMediaElementSource`, my audio is not playing even after connecting source to the destination. I was working on a project which uses Meyda's audio features to help represent these audio visually in an appropriate manner. I am new to Meyda and was trying to replicate their code example to test it out, but it did not work for me.

```js
// meydaScript.js
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const htmlAudioElement = document.getElementById("audio");
const source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(htmlAudioElement);
source.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.js"></script>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/meyda/dist/web/meyda.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <audio
                   controls
                   loop
                   crossorigin='anonymous'
                   id='audio'
                   src="assets/Ex2_sound1.wav"
                   >
            </audio>
            <br>
            <label for="level">Level</label>
            <input type="range"
                   id="levelRange"
                   name="level"
                   min="0.0"
                   max="1.0"
                   step="0.001"
                   />
        </main>
    </body>
    <script src="meydaScript.js"></script>
</html>
```

There is nothing in `main.js` for now, it is for adding some p5.js functionality later.
I've been scouring some posts online and in most cases, the solutions to the questions is just to add `source.connect(audioContext.destination);` I already have that, so what else am I missing? I've tried to `console.log` every single line in `meydaScript.js`, so I know my issue lies with `createMediaElementSource` or whatever it's related to.